# python stacked bar chart using categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Pandas dataframe (1800 obs) that looks something like this:

```
      A      B      C      D
 1   CL0    CL1    CL2    CL0
 2   CL2    CL1    CL1    CL3
 3   CL3    CL2    CL0    CL1
 .   ...    ...    ...    ...
 .   ...    ...    ...    ...
 n   CL2    CL1    CL0    CL3
```

I want to create a stacked bar chart that will have columns 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' on the x axis, and the percentage of each level in that feature on the y axis. Something like the picture below.

I'm guessing I need to tabulate the data somehow? But I don't know how to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C    D
1  CL0  CL1  CL2  CL0
2  CL2  CL1  CL1  CL3
3  CL3  CL2  CL0  CL1
```

Using [.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
counts = df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts() / len(x)).transpose()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
counts.plot(ax=ax,kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0)
vals = ax.get_yticks()
ax.set_yticklabels(['{:3.2f}%'.format(x*100) for x in vals])
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: how could i get a normal bar chart (not stacked with this code)? if i simply set `stacked=False` i have gaps between the bars of one column of the dataframe and the labels on the x-axis are not centered. any suggestions?

Comment: and how can i ensure to use the same colors for same category in subplots if i pass a `colormap`? Thanks in advance?