# How to create a stacked barchart for categorical variables using matplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a table with months as the columns and ids as row. Each cell contains one of three possible values, lets say a,b or c.

So my table looks something like this.

```
      Jan | Feb | Mar
  --------------------------
 1   | a  |  b  |  a
 2   | c  |  c  |  a
 3   | c  |  b  |  a
```

My goal is to create a stacked bar chart where the bins in the x-axis would be the months of the years, and the bars would contain the number of values for each type of cell type. So the barchart would end up something like this

```
 |
 |
 |   __
 |  |a |
 |  |__|
 |  | b|
 |  |  |
 |  |__|
 |  |c |
 |__|__|__________________
     jan     feb    mar
```

I tried using various barplots and histograms to try to make this work, but it gives me different types of errors.

Comment: If you are open to using pandas instead of matplotlib, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082440/python-stacked-bar-chart-using-categorical-data) that may help.